# Using timer/interval in a Function Component (React) vs Component

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, setinterval

The following snippet demonstrates that a javascript timer, or an interval used in a React Functional Component behaves differently than when a class React Component is used.
Also, I've seen different behavior. Like chaotic execution instead of the indicated timing.

Is there a workaround for this? Because I don't like to return to Component and not (or hardly) being able to use hooks anymore.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5mbqsk9/1/

````
const App = ()=>{
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const myfunc = ()=>{
    setCount(count+1);
  }
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    const tmr = setInterval(myfunc, 1000);
   return () => clearInterval(tmr);
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>app</h1>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}

class App2 extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
    this.tmr = {};
  }
  myfunc = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }
  tmr;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.tmr = setInterval(this.myfunc, 1000);

  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.tmr);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>App2</h1>
        {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
        <div>
      <div><App /></div>
      <div><App2/></div>
    </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Answer updated**: the problem was in your state updater function
I've played with your fiddle for 10 mins and found it working correctly. check this workaround

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const myfunc = () => {
      setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
    }
    const tmr = setInterval(myfunc, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(tmr);
  }, [])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Functional Component</h1>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}
class App2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
    this.tmr = {};
  }
  myfunc = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {count: prevState.count + 1}
    })
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.tmr = setInterval(this.myfunc, 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.tmr);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Class Component</h1>
        {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <div><App /></div>
    <div><App2/></div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

> if the new state is computed using the previous state, then use the functional update form of setState, i.e. `setCount(c => c + 1)` instead of `setCount(count + 1)` . Check https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Answer (score 0):

Your current functional component runs the effect only once, since you've passed an empty dependency array to your effect hook. The effect closes over the first value of `count` which is `0`, and sets it to `1`.

If all you want to do within the effect is update the state purely basis the previous state, you can do this simply by passing a function instead of a value to `setCount`:

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const tmr = setInterval(() => setCount(c => c+1), 1000);
   return () => clearInterval(tmr);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>app</h1>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, for a more general use case, if you want to use intervals / timeouts inside effects, you need to pass a dependency array to the effect hook of all values that you use internally - in this case `[count]`, since you use it *(indirectly)* via `myfunc`. Here's a sample:

```
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const myfunc = () => {
    setCount(count+1);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const tmr = setInterval(myfunc, 1000);
   return () => clearInterval(tmr);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>app</h1>
      {count}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that due to this, the interval timer will be set and cleared every second, and therefore you should be able to just use `setTimeout` instead.  In case you don't want the effect to clear the timer / interval on every update, you can consider a more verbose approach using [ref hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to store state variables and accessing the `ref` from the timer effect, instead of the state.

Comment: Great feedback. Works.